# Appending data to a scapy packet

Tags: python, packet, scapy

I know that I can append `Raw` data to a scapy packet like this

```
>>> p=Ether()/Raw("somedata")
>>> hexdump(p)
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
0000   FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00  00 00 00 00 90 00 73 6F   ..............so
0010   6D 65 64 61 74 61                                  medata
>>>
```

Here the data is appended in ASCII format.

But how could I append just numbers to a packet like this?

```
# Not real
>>> p = Ether()/RawNumbers(0x1234567891)
>>> hexdump(p)
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
0000   FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00  00 00 00 00 90 00 12 34   ................
0010   56 78 91                                           ...
>>>
```

Perhaps I could write a Packet-subclass which does this, but I'm not sure how to implement this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a `RawNumbers` layer as you can achieve this with python built-in functionality. Note that scapy will by default assume a raw layer if your layer is just a string.

```
>>> hexdump(Ether()/"\x12\x34\x56\x78\x91")
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
0000   FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00  00 00 00 00 90 00 12 34   ...............4
0010   56 78 91                                           Vx.
```

or (more convenient)

```
>>> hexdump(Ether()/"1234567891".decode("hex"))
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
0000   FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00  00 00 00 00 90 00 12 34   ...............4
0010   56 78 91                                           Vx.
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I did not think of that. Thank you.

Comment: There is one question left: What if I want to encode a single digit or tree digit number like 255? That does not seem to work, I get `TypeError: Odd-length-string`. Like `Ether()/"255".decode("hex")`. I would expect this to produce a `FF` byte?

Comment: typically you'll have to use `struct.pack` for this like `struct.pack("B",255)` is `\xff`. This packs the integer 255 into one `B`yte. see the help for struct.

Comment: see `struct` https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html and `str.decode` https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html